# I want to delete a video from my channel on Youtube using the API

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

This is my code:

```
YouTubeService serv = new YouTubeService("myDeleteService", YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY);            
serv.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
string feedUrl = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads", YOUTUBE_CHANNEL);
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + VideoId);
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
Video vid = (from vi in videoFeed.Entries
             where vi.VideoId == VideoId
             select vi).First<Google.YouTube.Video>();
request.Delete(vid);
```

The code breaks on the last line stating that object reference is not set to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue internal to the Google YouTube API. I'm having the same issue with good request and video objects. (Google API v1.9.0.0)

UPDATE: check out Claudio's response below. It is correct. I received an email back from support and forgot to update this answer:

this uri will fail:
"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID

this will work:
"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + accountName + "/uploads/" + videoID

Comment: Any solution? I have encountered the same problem.

Comment: I was also getting this error.your solution really help me out. +1 for you help

Answer (score 3):

The Delete method works as expected if you use the right url, i.e. the one from the /upload feed.

The entries in the /videos feed do not have an edit url which is the one that must be used to send a delete request. I just updated the library (rev. 1169) to return a more meaningful ArgumentNullException instead of the generic null reference.

Please use this code to delete a video you uploaded:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, VIDEO_ID));
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
request.Delete(video);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following:

```
CreateAuthenticatedRequest().Service.Delete(new Uri(GetVideoUploadUrl(videoId)));

    public static YouTubeRequest CreateAuthenticatedRequest()
    {
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.AppName"],  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.DeveloperKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.Email"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GData.Password"]);
        settings.Timeout = 1000000;
        return new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    }

    private static string GetVideoUploadUrl(string videoId)
    {
        return string.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/{0}", videoId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your LINQ query is probably returning nothing i.e., null. Check the `vid` variable in debugger or better yet, put an if condition to see whether `vid` has a valid value or not.

Comment: If the last line is where the error is, and its giving him a null exception then its also possible the request object is null.  It would be poor programing to allow an exception to occur just because Video is null.

Answer (score 0):

I spent over 5 hours trying to delete video with official sample code:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, VIDEO_ID));
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
request.Delete(video);
```

and I had and exception with 410 status code. I don't know why but according `ScottE` answer this code deletes video:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(YOUTUBE_CHANNEL, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.YouTube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/{0}", videoId));
request.Service.Delete(uri);
```

So I used `request.Service.Delete(uri);` except `request.Delete(video);`